# Paypal Vs Worldpay

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, worldpay

we are using Paypal Pro's Hosted solution for payments and finding that a lot of orders aren't completed when customers go to the payment page (one customer complained that they could only select Australia and United States for the shipping country!), we've found a lot of inconsistency with Paypal's service and 25% of orders aren't complete.

Worldpay seems like good alternative, **does anyone have experience of both Worldpay and Paypal, is Worldpay more reliable?**

Is Worldpay's documentation any good? Paypal's is terrible.

Are there any other alternatives?

We're trying to keep it simple by having the IMA and gateway all in one and process around £3k-£4k of payments a month.

Comment: Not really a programming question.

Comment: Yep had a look at the other stack forums and there aren't any e-commerces ones, and I've struggled to find any e-commerce forums that are any use, you must know about e-commerce to have bothered looking at this question, do you know of a more appropriate place I could stick it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Avangate - www.avangate.com

Answer (score 0):

This question is a few months old, but I'll answer it anyway.

PayPal's documentation is quite bad, but WorldPay isn't much better. In fact, they have documentation in place for somethings they don't yet support, and it can be difficult at times to figure out whether it's your code or that the service does not exist. This applies, in particular, to recurring payments.

We used to have PayPal, but we switched to WorldPay. My personal view is that PayPal is more flexible. WorldPay has its limitations - especially if you are selling SaaS and need some real flexibility, and as things get complicated for us, we have to get creative to work with it.

But at the end of the day, WorldPay support is a million times better than PayPal. For us, they are slightly cheaper (and will become cheaper this year hopefully as we have done some volume with them). Support responds to emails pretty regularly if not a 100%. Plus you can call. They're even happy to look at server logs and tell you why or how something got lost if it got lost.

To sum up and answer your question:

1. On Documentation - they are almost the same as PayPal.
2. On service, they are MUCH, MUCH better.
3. On price, they will eventually get better and hold money for only 48 hours before it hits your account (this is negotiable, btw).
4. Depending on what you want, there are other options available. If you want recurring payments and your IMA and PSP to come from one source, WorldPay is a good alternative, especially if you are based in the UK.
5. If IMA and PSP being the same is not important, I suggest checking out SagePay (UK) and Authorize.net (US) - IMHO they are both quite good. SagePay has its limitations, though, especially if you want recurring billing.

Please note, the above is based on my experience of selling customized, subscription based SaaS, not an online store.